# Admin grid multiselect column not work with filter

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, insertlisting, listing-component

If you go to the customer grid, there is an option to select the rows.

[image]

If you select some customers on the first page and filter another customer by email, the previously selected customers get unselected. But if you filter with full text or change page through pagination, it works perfectly.

I added customer grid into a form through inserListing and want it to work with fiter.
Please help me if there is any configuration.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue on my 2.4.2 instance. Both full text and filter by mail unchecked the selected customers (Even that it matches the search/filter). What Magento version are you using? And do you use any third party module?

Comment: hi @Jimmy,
My version is Magento/2.3 (Enterprise)

Comment: Sorry I don't have that version. But I think you are looking for a custom feature, not stock Magento

Comment: please see the video.
http://jecet.org/video.mp4